# Convergence of $\int_0^1\frac{1+x}{x^s}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

I am reviewing improper integrals and I claim that  $$\int_0^1\frac{1+x}{x^s}dx$$

converges when $s<1$. To see this, examine the limit $$\lim_{R\to 0^+}\int_R^1\frac{1+x}{x^s}dx= \lim_{R\to 0^+}\bigg(\frac{-1}{-s+1}+\frac{R^{-s+1}}{-s+1}\bigg)+\bigg(\frac{1}{2-s}-\frac{1}{2-s}R^{2-s}\bigg)$$

which defines the value of $s$, assuming we want to show convergence. My conclusion is that the asymptotic behavior of the function exist only at the single point of $x=0$, and hence it makes sense to talk about the area described by $$\int_0^1\frac{1+x}{x^s}dx$$

for the area near $x=0$ is quite small. The amount of the total area near $x=0$ is determined by the parameter $s$. Therefore, the convergence of such an integral is similar to asking, whether or it makes sense to approximate the integral with the described limit. Is this sensible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not approximating the integral. For improper integrals , the limit definition is how you make sense of it. And when you are evaluating the integral or rather the limit , you are not varying $s$. First fix an $s$ and then evaluate the limit wrt $R$. If it exsists you will get a value in terms of $s$ . Precisely it is just $\frac{1}{2-s}+\frac{1}{1-s}$ . This happes as for $s<1$ , $\lim_{R\to 0^{+}}R^{1-s}$ and $\lim_{R\to 0^{+}}R^{2-s}$  exists and is $0$.

For an improper integral in $(a,b]$ where the function has a infinite discontinuity at $x=a$ . We say that the improper integral converges if $\lim_{\varepsilon\to a^{+}}\int_{\varepsilon}^{b}f(x)\,dx$ exist and it is a finite number.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: when you think about $\lim_{R\to0,R\gt0}\int_R^1\frac{1+x}{x^s}\,\mathrm{d}x$, try looking at what happens when you perform the substitution $R=\frac{1}{r}$ and $x=\frac{1}{y}$. If your substitution is correctly done, you should obtain $$\lim_{r\to\infty}\int_1^ry^{s-2}+y^{s-3}\,\mathrm{d}y$$

Actual answer: $$\lim_{r\to\infty}\int_1^ry^{s-2}+y^{s-3}\,\mathrm{d}y=\lim_{r\to\infty}\left(\left(\frac{r^{s-1}}{s-1}-\frac{1}{s-1}\right)+\left(\frac{r^{s-2}}{s-2}-\frac{1}{s-2}\right)\right).$$ Now notice that $r^{s-1}$ is the dominating power here, so in order for $r^{s-1}$ to converge as $r\rightarrow\infty$, it is required that $s-1\lt0$. This is what determines that $s\lt1$ is the condition for convergence.

Your approach also works, but it makes the asymptotic behavior much harder to see. The condition for convergence in your case is that $R^{1-s}$ does not diverge, so $1-s\gt0$. This turns out to be equivalent, but not as intuitively seen.